# She maybe is his wife

Tags: adverbs

Can I use *Maybe* after the subject?

> She **maybe** is his wife.

Or It is come before the subject only.

> **Maybe** she is his wife.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of all the places to put **maybe**, that one is the least used, and would sound as though you are trying to draw specific attention to the word **maybe**, for example to correct another person for possibly jumping to the wrong conclusion.

> Maybe she's his wife.
>
> She's his wife, maybe.
>
> She's maybe his wife.
>
> She maybe is his wife. <sup>unusual location</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to write "She may be his wife" which has the same meaning as "Maybe she is his wife"

Comment: Thank you, but I meant "maybe" as adverb not "may be" as modal verb with auxiliary "be" verb

Comment: @Shannak Dargon is correct, you cannot have the adverb "maybe" before  *is*, the adverb "maybe" usually goes in front position. But you can use may+V to express exactly the same thing. You might find [this page](http://www.woodwardenglish.com/maybe-may-be-difference/) useful.

Comment: @Laure I would agree that *she maybe is his wife* is not idiomatic. Though the beauty of English is that there are usually a number of different ways of saying the same thing. There is nothing wrong with saying *Maybe she is his wife* or *Perhaps she is his wife*, or even *She, perhaps, is his wife*.

Comment: @Laure I apologise. My remark was essentially addressed to Dargon's answer, which seemed a trifle specific in saying "I think you want to write...".

Comment: @WS2 No problem.